# Gradle won't resolve dependency (Maven will)

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-3, restlet

My project has dependencies configured through gradle. I would like to add the following dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.restlet.jse', name: 'org.restlet.ext.apispark', version: '2.3.1'
```

Which can be found in the following repository (which I have added to my build.gradle):

```
maven {
    url "http://maven.restlet.org"
}
```

However when I do that I get the following error:

```
Could not find org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.lib.swagger-models:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.
http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.lib.swagger-models/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.lib.swagger-models/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/org.restlet.lib.swagger-models-1.5.0-null-null.pom
http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.lib.swagger-models/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/org.restlet.lib.swagger-models-1.5.0-null-null.jar
Required by: org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.apispark:2.3.1
```

I can see that the jar is in fact in the repository however Gradle is not looking for it in the right location for reasons unknown to me. Why is it not using the version in the filename but rather 1.5.0-null-null.

I have made a made a Maven project with the same dependency defined in the pom.xml which works.

[Link to working pom.xml that has same dependency](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-tutorial/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.tutorial.webapi/pom.xml)

How can this issue be resolved? I'm at this point also interesting in more manual solutions :) Thank you.

Comment: Littlebit off topic. Is gradle using the same repositories as maven does?

Comment: Can you show the maven config that works?

Comment: @Antoniossss gradle uses the repositories you tell it to use. It CAN use Maven Central, but it can use other repos as well, just like maven. See http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N105A1 for an example of how to use Maven Central with gradle.

Comment: @Antoniossss No. Gradle was configured to use maven central and maven.restlet.org. Maven was using Maven.restlet.org and https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/releases/. However the problem is that maven could resolve a specific dependecy in maven.restlet.org that gradle couldn't.

Comment: @superbob I have added a link to the maven pom.xml that I'm somewhat trying to replicate in gradle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Diagnosis

It seems to be related to snapshot "*uniqueness*". For information on Maven repositories, snapshots artifacts can be deployed "*unique*" or "*non-unique*".

- **Unique snapshots:** Each time you deploy a snapshot, it is tagged with a **timestamp** and a **buildNumber**, these timestamp and buildNumber are written in the `maven-metadata.xml` file and they are appended to its name that ends up like: `artifactName-version-timestamp-buildNumber.jar`.
- **Non-unique snapshots:** Each time you deploy a snapshot it overwrites the previous version, his name ends up like: `artifactName-version.jar`.

It is recommended to use unique snapshot as one can refer precisely to one version of the artifact if needed.

The problem is that "*http://maven.restlet.org*" seems to use non-unique snapshots and sadly, gradle seems to have problems to deal with non-unique snapshots: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3164.

If you look at http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.lib.org.restlet.lib.swagger-models/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml you can clearly see `null` in *timestamp* and *buildNumber* tags:

```
<metadata>
  [...]
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>null</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>null</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>null</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

I think that's where the "`null-null`" comes from.

## Solution 1 - flatDir

To deal with it you can manually download the artifact, put it in a directory, for example "lib" and create a [flatDir](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:flat_dir_resolver) repository:

```
repositories {
    [...]
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
    [...]
}
```

It's not an ideal solution, but it works.

## Solution 2 - jcenter repository

[Suggested by Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557622/gradle-wont-resolve-dependency-maven-will#answer-29563227)

Add the [jcenter repository](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) that contains your missing dependency and that Gradle handles well.

Since [Gradle 1.7](http://gradle.org/docs/1.7/release-notes#jcenter-repository-support) you can simply define it with:

```
repositories {
    [...]
    jcenter()
    [...]
}
```

Comment: I think we can also fix the restlet repository. I've added an issue for that: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1054

Comment: @ThierryBoileau, that would be nice indeed :) Maven official documentation is not perfectly clear on that topic (snapshot uniqueness). Especially regarding the changes between maven versions (1->2, 2->3). That's why I didn't provide many links to maven.org in my answer. But you should be able to figure out the details anyway

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you need other repositories to download all the dependencies.  Probably maven handle this transparently. The following script downloads all dependencies successfully when `cp` task is run:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
   lol
}

repositories {
   jcenter()
   mavenCentral()
   maven {
      url "http://maven.restlet.org"
   }
   maven {
      url "https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/"
   }
}

dependencies {
   lol group: 'org.restlet.jse', name: 'org.restlet.ext.apispark', version: '2.3.1'
}

task cp(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.lol
   into 'deps'
}
```

Comment: That's because jcenter contains the missing dependency, maven central does not.

Comment: Yes it does. I don't mean this solution is bad. But it is not "Strange". Moreover, it is not obvious, reading the response, that the solution is really "_adding the jcenter repository_". That might be highlighted to make it clearer.

Comment: This is the solution I actually went with in my implementation. However the answer doesn't try to explain why it is that it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: @Opal, unless it bothers you, I will include your solution in my answer to make a more complete answer, as OP actually used your solution. PS: I upvoted your answer